# React and srcSet: images loading time

Tags: reactjs, srcset

I am working with React. I have a grid with some images, with `srcset` —`srcSet` in React—. Each image looks something like this:

```
<img 
    class="App-gridImage" 
    src="https://picsum.photos/1200?image=5" sizes="600px" 
    srcSet="
        https://picsum.photos/200?image=5 200w, 
        https://picsum.photos/400?image=5 400w, 
        https://picsum.photos/1200?image=5 1200w, 
        https://picsum.photos/2400?image=5 2400w, 
    "
/>
```

Even using `srcSet`, the images need some time to load. I just created a sandbox to demonstrate it. You will only notice the delay in the first load; after it, images are cached, so it will be necessary to delete caché to appreciate it again: https://codesandbox.io/s/x21y88q39o

I would like to know if `srcset` is properly used here, and what other strategies can I use to avoid that problem

Comment: Could you clarify what is the problem?

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, the images take ages to load, and I was wondering if I was using srcset properly here.